# WELD-001519 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for an abstract class 'xxx'. It will not be possible to produce instances of this type

Tags: jsf, glassfish, cdi, omnifaces, weld

I'm running an application in the following environment.

- GlassFish Server 4.0
- Mojarra 2.2.4
- PrimeFaces 4.0 final
- PrimeFaces Extension 1.1.0
- OmniFaces 1.6.3

After adding OmniFaces, the following warnings appear on the server terminal.

```
WARNING:   WELD-001519 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for an abstract class org.omnifaces.eventlistener.DefaultServletContextListener. It will not be possible to produce instances of this type!    
WARNING:   WELD-001519 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for an abstract class org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter. It will not be possible to produce instances of this type!

//WARNING:   Class 'javax.ejb.PostActivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
//WARNING:   Class 'javax.ejb.PrePassivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
INFO:   Initializing Mojarra 2.2.4 ( 20131003-1354 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.4@12574) for context '/Project-war'

WARNING:   WELD-001529 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for a class org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory which does not have any appropriate constructor.
WARNING:   WELD-001529 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for a class org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContextFactory which does not have any appropriate constructor.
WARNING:   WELD-001529 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for a class org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContextFactory which does not have any appropriate constructor.
WARNING:   WELD-001529 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for a class org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContextFactory which does not have any appropriate constructor.

INFO:   Running on PrimeFaces 4.0
INFO:   Running on PrimeFaces Extensions null
INFO:   Using OmniFaces version null

INFO:   Loading application [Project#Project-war.war] at [Project-war]
INFO:   Project was successfully deployed in 22,734 milliseconds.
```

Is there any problem with OmniFaces in the given environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, those are just warnings, not errors. Weld is just not able to create injection targets for abstract classes or classes which does not have a default constructor. Injection targets need to be able to do `Class.forName(className).newInstance()` without any trouble.

This disturbance in logging is already reported as [Weld issue 1547](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-1547) and hereby the WARNING level is lowered to DEBUG level since Weld 2.1.1 / 2.2.0.

Noted should be that there's another bug, most likely related to GlassFish classloading. OmniFaces has namely a [`VetoAnnotatedTypeExtension`](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/VetoAnnotatedTypeExtension.java) which should exclude all those OmniFaces classes from unnecessarily being scanned as CDI managed beans. This works fine when Weld is used in Tomcat 7 and JBoss 6/7/8. I.e. those warnings doesn't appear at all for OmniFaces classes.