# Passthrough custom HTML5 attributes using Omnifaces

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

As it's described in the [documentation](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/2.0/org/omnifaces/renderkit/Html5RenderKit.html) that in order to pass custom HTML5 attributes we have to declare the context-parameter `org.omnifaces.HTML5_RENDER_KIT_PASSTHROUGH_ATTRIBUTES`, passing the fully qualified name of a class as a key and the value as commaseparated string of names of passthrough attributes.

What I've done is this:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.HTML5_RENDER_KIT_PASSTHROUGH_ATTRIBUTES</param-name>
    <param-value>
        javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm=data-parsley-validate; <!-- test also javax.faces.component.UIForm -->
        javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText=data-parsley-type;            
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Also I've registered the `render-kit-factory`

```xml
<factory>
    <render-kit-factory>org.omnifaces.renderkit.Html5RenderKitFactory</render-kit-factory>
</factory>
```

And of course all this goes into the [`faces-config.xml`](https://github.com/hatemalimam/HTML5Passthrough/blob/ab05d7d957a54bd806b25bb796444d52c06eb12c/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml).
Unfortunately I have no luck in getting it to work, I'm not sure what is missing.

I have created a very basic project on [github](https://github.com/hatemalimam/HTML5Passthrough/tree/ab05d7d957a54bd806b25bb796444d52c06eb12c) containing only [one page](https://github.com/hatemalimam/HTML5Passthrough/blob/ab05d7d957a54bd806b25bb796444d52c06eb12c/src/main/webapp/index.xhtml), and inside it one form and an inputText.

I have tested this in **three** environments:

***First one***

- GlassFish Edition 4.0 (build 89) - *I'm having some [warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372439/weld-001519-an-injectiontarget-implementation-is-created-for-an-abstract-class) also*
- Mojarra 2.2.0
- Omnifaces 1.8.1

***Second one***

- JBoss Application Server 7.1.1
- Mojarra 2.1.11
- Omnifaces 1.8.1

***Third one***

- jetty 9.1.1
- Mojarra 2.2.0
- Omnifaces 1.8.1

---

My first assumption was the version of Mojarra which 2.2 but I also tested on 2.1 the same result, it seems I'm missing something here since I have a very clean example/project.

I've already managed to pass those custom attributes by implementing different renderers, but it's less headache for me to use the Omnifaces one, also tested to pass `autocomplete` to the form which is initially supported attribute by this renderer and it works fine.

**Note**: I know that in JSF 2.2 we can pass HTML5 easily, in my case the app should be eligible to work on 2.2 or 2.1 .

Comment: Please don't delete the question. This solved the issue I was solving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<context-param>` belongs in `web.xml`, not `faces-config.xml`.

I [just](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/2c0e40ee2956d1e231e486c6a9113bf58f7e4b7a) clarified the javadocs on this.

Comment: Maybe I should delete the question ?

Comment: It wasn't explicit enough mentioned in the docs. I took this as an opportunity to update the docs. Another starter may hit the same problem in the future when not having digested enough cafein for the day.

Comment: I mean I've already got tons of context-params in my project yet I've put it in the faces-config, I feel like a starter today -_- .. anyway thank you and I'll keep the question as a Stigma :)

Comment: By the way, Eclipse complained about an unknown element with a red underline when I try `<context-param>` in `faces-config.xml`. Didn't Netbeans do that? Might as well blame Netbeans for that :)

Comment: No! usually I always use Eclipse, but my current project has an extensive front-end stuff (less, js libs) and NetBeans makes them more easy for me.. I'm not sure how NetBEans didn't complain !

Comment: Now I've got another weird thing, passing a custom attr to the form would repeat that attr on [every div](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/HTML5Passthrough/) (not only div apparently), I have updated [github](https://github.com/hatemalimam/HTML5Passthrough/blob/master/src/main/webapp/index.xhtml) !

Comment: This is consequence of the workaround for broken renderers (ones in older PrimeFaces versions). I decided to remove it for OmniFaces 2.0 as per https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/9fa0c3b9842830073dccc2f98e2c839ca563f871 This is indeed too messy.

Comment: I see, I'll stick with my renderers for the moment till 2.0 is a release. Thank you.