# WARNING: Parameter 1 of type List<Bean<?>> from public void org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRepository.setXxx is not resolvable to a concrete type

Tags: jsf, glassfish, cdi, omnifaces, weld

I'm using Omnifaces 1.8.1 and Whenever I deploy my application to Glassfish I get the following warning which causes some delay in the deploy process.

```
Warning:   WELD-001519 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for an abstract class org.omnifaces.eventlistener.DefaultHttpSessionListener. It will not be possible to produce instances of this type!
Warning:   WELD-001519 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for an abstract class org.omnifaces.eventlistener.DefaultServletContextListener. It will not be possible to produce instances of this type!
Warning:   WELD-001519 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for an abstract class org.omnifaces.eventlistener.DefaultServletRequestListener. It will not be possible to produce instances of this type!
Warning:   WELD-001519 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for an abstract class org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter. It will not be possible to produce instances of this type!

Warning:   The following warnings have been detected: 

WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.util.List<javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean<?>> from public void org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRepository.setApplicationScopedBeans(java.util.List<javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean<?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.   
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.List<javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean<?>>> from public void org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRepository.setRequestScopedBeansViewId(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.List<javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean<?>>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.List<javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean<?>>> from public void org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRepository.setRequestScopedBeansRequestURI(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.List<javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean<?>>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.util.List<javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean<?>> from public void org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRepository.setSessionScopedBeans(java.util.List<javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean<?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
```

I have upgraded to Omnifaces 2.0 and still getting the same warning which is quite annoying in the development process where deployment is applied frequently. What is causing these warnings?

PS: Development environment:

- Glassfish 4.1
- Java 8
- JSF 2.2.0 (Mojarra)
- Primefaces 4.0
- Netbeans 8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is Weld specific. Those warnings are innocent and actually doesn't significantly delay deploy.

As to unresolvable parameter warning, CDI indeed doesn't support proxying methods with wildcard-parameterized arguments like `List<?>`. The annoyance of those warnings is however understood. As those methods are package-private anyway, I've reduced as per [this commit](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/94f4627a16d28cc90b874d51972ffd7884c733d6) the visibility so that Weld doesn't attempt to inspect them. The fix is available in [OmniFaces 2.1 SNAPSHOT](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/2.1-SNAPSHOT/).

As to WELD-001519 warning on abstract classes, this is indeed totally unnecessary. This is already [fixed](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-1547) in Weld 2.1.1/2.2.0. See also the duplicate question: [WELD-001519 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for an abstract class 'xxx'. It will not be possible to produce instances of this type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372439/weld-001519-an-injectiontarget-implementation-is-created-for-an-abstract-class).